# Adding 2 jQuery scripts into 1 file

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#previous' 


});
});

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a. lightbox').lightBox();
});
</script>
</script>
```

1. The problem: When i use the code in separate files files, it works just fine, but when i add the lightbox to the carousel script or vice versa. Both of them stop working.

I just started using `jQuery and plugins`. Ran into a problem and i don't quite know how to fix it, or whats wrong. I want to have a carousel and a lightbox in my website, but whenever i add the script, it goes, it stops working.

Got the source files for the lightbox from http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ and the jquery library from the jquery website. for both the carousel and the lightbox.

Reply will be much appreciated.

Now the lightbox only works but not the carousel

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#previous' 

     // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script><script
type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox();
});
</script>
```